# Firebase Connection error when date changed on device

Tags: ios, firebase

I have setup my app's database on firebase. The app fetches data normally,
but when I change the date on device to 25th march,2019 or after that, it starts show error on console as below. Current date is 14th November, 2018.
Is there any kind of validation on firebase server.

> [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID003009] Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17025c0e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the date too far into the future you are preventing the SSL handshake from completing successfully.

The status code of [-9807](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-9807) indicates that something in the certificate chain is invalid; It is likely that a certificate in the chain expires before the 25th of March 2019. Because a certificate has expired, an SSL connection cannot be made.